# (Python) Simple Action Server - register_goal_callback executes unexpectedly

Tags: ros, python, actionlib, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to write a simple action server using the goal callback method as described in the tutorial in C++ [over here](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28GoalCallbackMethod%29), however I'm trying to rewrite it in Python. If it works, I would definitely suggest it as an addition to the `actionlib` tutorials.

I have put together more or less the whole thing, but clearly I'm missing something essential around the registration of the callbacks. **As soon as I call the** `_as.register_goal_callback(self.goalCB())` **the program will attempt to execute the callback immediately and then complain that it doesn't have a goal. The same happens for the** `_as.register_preempt_callback(self.preemptCB())` **which preempts itself immediately. All this happens before the server is even started.**

I suppose this is not meant to be happening, but I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

> [ERROR] [1523131943.200392]: Attempting to accept the next goal when a new goal is not available

> [INFO] [1523131943.200585]: /averaging : Preempted

> [ERROR] [1523131943.200728]: Attempt to get a goal id on an uninitialized ServerGoalHandle

> [ERROR] [1523131943.200860]: Attempt to get a goal id on an uninitialized ServerGoalHandle

> [ERROR] [1523131943.200988]: Attempt to set status on an uninitialized ServerGoalHandle

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import actionlib
import actionlib_tutorials.msg
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from math import pow, sqrt, fabs

class AveragingAction(object):
    # create messages that are used to publish feedback/result
    _feedback = actionlib_tutorials.msg.AveragingActionFeedback()
    _result = actionlib_tutorials.msg.AveragingActionResult()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._action_name = name
        self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer(name=self._action_name, ActionSpec=actionlib_tutorials.msg.AveragingAction, auto_start=False)

        self._as.register_goal_callback(self.goalCB())
        self._as.register_preempt_callback(self.preemptCB())

        self._as.start()
        rospy.loginfo("Starting an ActionServer")

        self._sub = rospy.Subscriber("/random_number", Float32, callback=self.analysisCB)

        self._msg = Float32()

    def goalCB(self):
        self._data_count = 0
        self._sum = 0
        self._sum_sq = 0

        self._goal = self._as.accept_new_goal()

    def preemptCB(self):
        rospy.loginfo("{} : Preempted".format(self._action_name))
        self._as.set_preempted()
    ...
```

(there is more code, but I don't think that's relevant anymore)

I have gone through the [simple_action_callback.py](https://github.com/strawlab/ros_common/blob/master/actionlib/src/actionlib/simple_action_server.py) to figure out why it is  getting called, but I'm not sure I get what's going on because I'm probably missing out something with the goal registration. All that's written there is this :

```
## @brief Allows users to register a callback to be invoked when a new goal is available
## @param cb The callback to be invoked
def register_goal_callback(self,cb):
    if self.execute_callback:
        rospy.logwarn("Cannot call SimpleActionServer.register_goal_callback() because an executeCallback exists. Not going to register it.");
    else:
        self.goal_callback = cb;
```

Which would make me think that it would stay registered and activate only when a new goal arrives. But it activates immediately. Moreover a condition `if self._as.is_new_goal_available():` comes out `False` when I place it inside the `goalCB()` which really confuses me.

I hope this is not too verbose. I can edit it down if needed.

FYI I'm using

- ROS Kinetic distribution
- Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
- actionlib 1.11.13
- rospy 1.12.13

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287926/(python)-simple-action-server---register_goal_callback-executes-unexpectedly/) by [AdamSorrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31651/adamsorrel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are invoking the callback `self.goalCB()` instead of just passing the function `self.goalCB`.

Can you try to remove the parenthesis when you register the callbacks?

```
self._as.register_goal_callback(self.goalCB)
self._as.register_preempt_callback(self.preemptCB)
```

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdamSorrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31651/adamsorrel/) on 2018-04-09**:
Yes! That's it. Thanks so much!  I feel so stupid now, but this is genuinely a great help.